# Python pandas: set consecutive index (starting at 0) for every group in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, indexing

I have a dataframe sorted and grouped by serial number, then date:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["serial_num" , "date"])
df = df.groupby(df['serial_num'])['date'].some_function()
```

Dataframe

```
    serial_num       date
0            1 2001-01-01
1            1 2001-02-01
2            1 2001-03-01
3            1 2001-04-01
4            3 2003-05-01
5            3 2003-06-01
6            3 2003-07-01
7            7 2005-07-01
8            7 2005-08-01
9            7 2005-09-01
10           7 2005-10-01
11           7 2005-11-01
12           7 2005-12-01
```

Each unique `serial_num` group will be a line on a line graph.

The way it is graphed now, each line is a time series that starts at a different point -- because the first `date` is different for every `serial_num` group.

I need the x-axis of the graph to be `time` instead of `date`. All lines on the graph will start at the same point - the origin of the x-axis of my graph.

I think the easiest way to do this would be to add a consecutive index that starts at `0` for each group, like this:

```
    serial_num       date  new_index
0            1 2001-01-01          0
1            1 2001-02-01          1
2            1 2001-03-01          2
3            1 2001-04-01          3
4            3 2003-05-01          0
5            3 2003-06-01          1
6            3 2003-07-01          2
7            7 2005-07-01          0
8            7 2005-08-01          1
9            7 2005-09-01          2
10           7 2005-10-01          3
11           7 2005-11-01          4
12           7 2005-12-01          5
```

Then, I think I will be able to graph (in Plotly) with all lines starting at the same point (the `0` index will be the first data point for each `serial_num`.

NOTE: each `serial_num` group has a different number of data points.

I'm unsure how to index with groupby this way. Please help! Or if you know another method that will accomplish the same goal, please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumcount`:

```
df["new_index"] = df.groupby("serial_num").cumcount()
print(df)

==>

    serial_num        date  new_index
0            1  2001-01-01          0
1            1  2001-02-01          1
2            1  2001-03-01          2
3            1  2001-04-01          3
4            3  2003-05-01          0
5            3  2003-06-01          1
6            3  2003-07-01          2
7            7  2005-07-01          0
8            7  2005-08-01          1
9            7  2005-09-01          2
10           7  2005-10-01          3
11           7  2005-11-01          4
12           7  2005-12-01          5
```